# What means Javascript comma separated functions

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am reading a javscript dojo library and I see many complex functions which I can't understand. For example:

```
_refreshUI: function () {
    this._hasUI && (g.empty(this.flowContainer), f.forEach(this.basemaps, function (a, b) { a.id || (a.id = "basemap_" + b); this.flowContainer.appendChild(this._buildNodeLayout(a))
}, this), g.create("br", { style: { clear: "both" } }, this.flowContainer), this._markSelected(this._selectedBasemap))
```

this function is written on a single line. It contains functions separated with commas. So I can not read it.

I do not ask what the above function does.

What does this mean?:

```
this._hasUI && (firstFunction, secondFunction, ...)
```

What does it do? Or how can I write it clearly?

Comment: `if this._hasUI` true than call functions. Look at [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: It is same as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/64mSf/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a way of only executing the functions if `this._hasUI` resolves to true.

Try this:

```
true && (console.log(1), console.log(2));
```

And this:

```
false && (console.log(1), console.log(2));
```

You'll see that only the first line will run the `console.log()` functions.

This is because the boolean AND operator (`&&`) is evaluated lazily. If the left side of the operator resolves to `false`, the interpreter won't bother evaluating the right side, because the operation can never result in `true`. This means the functions on the right will only be executed if the left side is a [truthy value](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

Comment: To make the answer more complete, the syntax `(function1, function2)`
will execute both functions (from left to right) and will return whatever `function2` returns regardless of what `function1` returns.

Comment: @user2070775 I think your comment is more in line with what I would imagine the OP was asking

Answer (score 0):

Let us put this inside an object, I surrounded the functions using parenthesis for readability :

```
var myObj = {
    _hasUI : true,
    _markSelected : function(arg){some logic}
    _refreshUI: function() {
                 this._hasUI &&  
                 (
                      // Strat evaluation from the left to right
                                 (g.empty(this.flowContainer), 
                                 (f.forEach(...)                ), 
                                 (g.create(args)                ), 
                                 (this._markSelected(arg)   )
                     // End evaluation and return
                     // the result of this._markSelected(arg)
                 )
}
```

basically, that means if this._hasUI is true **continue** the execution what you find after. In this case, execute/evaluate the first function then the second function.. until the last function and it will  **return the result of the last function only** .
you can find something else, not just a function you can find comparisons variable any expression...

look at the same code with integers:

```
var secondExempleObj = {
    _hasUI : true, // change it to false and see the difference
    _refreshUI: function () {
        return ( this._hasUI && (1,false,3,4) )
    }
}
console.log('result : ' + secongExempleObj ._refreshUI());
// if _hasUI == true then the resutl will be 4
// if _hasUI  == false you will get false
// _hasUI  will work just like light switch if true -> continue to evaluate the rest of expressions else get out of there so we can replace it like so

var thirdObj  = {
    numbers : [1,87,30],
    sumFunction : function(n1,n2,n3){ console.log(n1+n2+n3) },
    _hasUI : true,
    _refreshUI: function () {
        if(this._hasUI == true){          
            return (1,false,this.sumFunction(...this.numbers),4)
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
}
console.log('result  : ' + thirdObj._refreshUI());
// it will console log 118 then 4 
// if you switch _hasUI to false it will logout false
```

hope that make sense to you